# LINQ vs normal iteration

Tags: performance, linq

I'm a LINQ newbie, and I was wondering what the benefits/disadvantages of using LINQ instead of normal loop iteration were? I understand that LINQ is easier to read, but are there efficiency issues and as such where are they? Is it particular structures/data/queries or just in general they are worse?

Comment: You shouldn't be concerned with performance issues until you have them. Up until then this is an academic exercise that is likely to waste your time. Quite often you only notice any difference when you have millions of items in your queries. You should be more concerned with maintainability because that is far more likely to be of value to you.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense to only learn about it when I need it. I do quite a bit of Machine Learning so I tend to think more about performance than I should.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ has a few (relatively minor) performance issues because

- Passing Lambdas around is slightly slower than passing around method pointers, since vairables captured in a lambda are stored in a special class generated by the compiler. This can be seen if you open your output using [ILDasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- Method pointers are slightly slower than passing around methods directly, because of the type safety the runtime has to check when passing
- So, iterating a sequence directly with lots of break and continue statements is certainly the fastest way, strictly speaking, but not necesarilly the best.

The advantage of using Linq (syntax or the extension methods in System.Linq.Enumerable class)

- is that it's much easier to read and write, especially when you get complex queries such as joins, zips, aggregations, and so on, and is especially handy to have these methods return values instead of having to write helper functions yourself.
- This can be very important since it means you'll be able to add things to your program faster, rather than tweaking a couple ms out of it by using a foreach loop.
- Realitsically, the difference is so minimal in most cases, you'd want to set up both ways and run speed tests side by side before deciding one way was "better."

Also, things relatively unreasonable with iterating

- being able to use [Queryables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) to build your method calls into something else, such as Linq to SQL or other database wrapper which you then call as if it were just more LINQ
- Being able to quickl parallelize with [.AsParallel()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd413237%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the big write up. I'm guessing its minor performance decreases are just that, and will be scaleable then. LINQ does seem to be the better way unless you really need to squeeze out performance, in which case you probably wouldn't use .net anyway... though being able to parallelize easily might mitigate that